# Quality loss when PDF opened in Preview

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, resolution, mac, osx

I just saved an `.ai` file as a `.pdf` and opened it afterwards to check size and quality. This is when I noticed the saved file was lower in both color and resolution, than the original `.ai` file.

After some resaving and playing with settings, I decided to open the file in Google Chrome. This shows the file in full-res and with the right colors.

The question now is: Why does it do this in Preview on Mac OS X? What is the factor that kills resolution and color? Is there a fix for Preview, or should I start using a different PDF-viewer?

See the following file for an example of quality difference (Preview > Illustrator > Chrome)
[image]

[Link to high-res image](http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/uploads/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-28%20at%2013.33.07.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Preview is simply a *terrible* PDF viewer. It has many rendering issues with PDFs.

Preview is designed by Apple to view PDFs for average home end-users. It is not designed to be a professional PDF viewer. Apple simply *appears* to not be concerned with many rendering issues in Preview where PDFs are concerned. What you are describing I'd actually call one of the more *minor* issues with Preview's PDF render engine. For example, try using spot colors in a PDF and view it in Preview.....

If you want accurate display of PDFs use Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Horrible. At first I thought something was wrong with the way I was saving the file. I've seen it before with colors, which displayed different from the original file. Will drop Preview for PDF files. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Next to that, Preview is horribly slow compared to the PDF-viewer in Chrome. So, good riddance!

Comment: Browser PDF render engines aren't much better than Preview.