# Save as PDF in Photoshop: error and/or bad result

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, resolution, affinity-designer

I've a problem exporting PSD files into PDF. 
DISCLAIMER: I rarely work with PDF and I'm probably doing a rookie mistake here.

I have to print a 70x100cm BW poster so I created a new file 70x100 cm at 300ppi. Once it was completed I went into the save as -> photoshop PDF (selected "as a copy", not Layers) -> high quality print. When I preview the PDF in Preview (I don't have creative cloud, only photoshop + lightroom plan, so I don't have Acrobat PRO) at print size has a lower resolution then expected. I exported the very same file saved as PSD with Affinity Photo and got a much better result with "high quality print" PDF option.

See screenshot attached: Left is Affinity; Right is Photohsop.

[image: screenshot]

NOTES: 
1) I had multiple times an error while saving as PDF that I solved holding CMD+SHIFT+ALT while launching the app and resetting the ps preferences.
2) It takes FOREVER, like 15 mins to save the file
3) The file generated with PS is about 40Mb, the one generated in Affinity is about 15Mb

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Thanks for your help
Have a nice day you all

Comment: I probably found an answer here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41425/quality-loss-when-pdf-opened-in-preview?rq=1

Preview is doing an awful work and that's ok, when I open it in Chrome looks great at print size. Now I'm trying to print it to see if it looks good on paper.